# Using iOS compression library to decompress zlib compressed data keeps returning NSCocoaErrorDomain code=5377

Tags: ios, swift, compression, zlib

I'm writing an iOS app that wants to read in a zlib compressed data file and uncompress it.    This should be easy using the builtin compression library and zlib is one of the supported compression algorithms.  Here is my code:
'''
import Compression

```
do {
   let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
   print("read data of size \(fileData.count) bytes")
   decompressedData = try (data as NSData).decompressed(using: .zlib) as Data
}
catch {
   print("Failed to decompress data: \(error)")
}
```

'''

The decompression keeps failing with Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=5377.

I've verified that the file is correctly compressed using zlib compression.  I can compress and uncompress the data file on both macos and linux using a python program that uses zlib compression.  I can also do the same with zlib-flate.  I correctly read the compressed file into a Data object and is 4581383 bytes.

Any suggestions as to why I can't decompress the data?

Thanks,

Bobby

Comment: Maybe take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65234249/477878)?

Comment: You need to put the first several bytes of your compressed data in the question in hex or base64 so we can what it actually is.

Comment: First few bytes were 120, 156, 108, 189, 205 . . . .  Turns out the first two 120=0x78, 156=0x9c.  Based on the comment above, deleting those two bytes from the buffer caused the buffer to be successfully decompressed!

Comment: Those two bytes are the zlib header. There are also four bytes at the end for an integrity check. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Swift's "zlib" is raw deflate. You may have zlib-wrapped deflate data. You would need to process the zlib header and trailer yourself (see [RFC 1950](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1950)), and then pass the raw deflate data to Swift's decompressor.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, last 4 bytes seem to be the checksum.  I've used removeLast(4) to get rid of them.  Having the checksum does not seem to effect the zlib decompression from the iOS Compression library though.

Comment: It's there for you to use to verify that the data came across ok.

Answer (score 0):

I used the [answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575923/zlib-in-iphone-unable-to-decompress-data/65234249#65234249) suggested by @joachim-isaksson.

I removed the first two bytes 0x78 and 0x9c and then zlib decompression started working.

```
data.removeFirst(2)
```